# Queue management and new thread

Tags: c#

using C# on the .Net 4.0 framework, I have a Windows Forms main thread (the only one,  until now) that waits for filesystem events and then must start some predefined processing on the files provided by those events.

I am planning to do the following:

- A1. To immediately create a separate thread when the main process start;
- A2. Have the main thread to put in a Queue (FIFO) the file names to be
  processed;
- A3. Have the new thread triggered by a timer every n
  seconds;
- A4. Have the new thread read the queue, if there is an item
  to perform the processing, then have it cancel the queue item just
  processed.

Because I never have programmed threads before (I am basically using the Albahari as my compass) but I definitely want to, I have a few questions just to spot possible heavy headache in advance:

- Q1. May I incur into concurrence problems on the Queue if the main process writes only and the new ones cancel only queue items? In other words: Is synchronization a significant issue in this case?
- Q2. I have seen that I could create a new thread from scratch or can reuse one of the threads made available from an existing pool. It is safer / simpler to use threads from the pool in this context?
- Q3. Are there any drawbacks to keeping alive the new thread indefinitely and responding only to timer until the main process is closed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841390/c-how-to-use-a-mutex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting .Net Framework 4, the [Blocking Collection](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT) sounds like it will solve your issues; i.e. creating a new thread pooled thread when "work" items become available on the queue (added to the queue on the event handler when new files are added) and process them asynchronously on that thread.

You can use one in a producer/consumer queue:

E.g.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Producer/consumer queue. Used when a task needs executing, it’s enqueued to ensure order, 
/// allowing the caller to get on with other things. The number of consumers can be defined, 
/// each running on a thread pool task thread. 
/// Adapted from: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT
/// </summary>
public class ProducerConsumerQueue : IDisposable
{
    private BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    public ProducerConsumerQueue(int workerCount)
    {
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    { 
        _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); 
    }

    public void EnqueueTask(Action action) 
    { 
        _taskQ.Add(action); 
    }

    private void Consume()
    {
        // This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
        // are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called.
        // Note: This removes AND returns items from the collection.
        foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // Perform task.
            action();
        }
    }
}
```