# Why this C# code throws SemaphoreFullException?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have following code which throws `SemaphoreFullException`, I don't understand why ?

If I change  `_semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 2)` to

```
 _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, int.MaxValue)
```

then all works fine.
Can anyone please find fault with this code and explain to me.

```
 class BlockingQueue<T>
    {
        private Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();
        private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 2);
        public void Enqueue(T data)
        {
            if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            lock (_queue)
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(data);
            }
            _semaphore.Release();
        }

        public T Dequeue()
        {
            _semaphore.Wait();
            lock (_queue)
            {
                return _queue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private static BlockingQueue<string> _bq = new BlockingQueue<string>();
        public static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                _bq.Enqueue("item-" + i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(Produce);
                t.Start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(Consume);
                t.Start();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Random _random = new Random();
        private static void Produce()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _bq.Enqueue("item-" + _random.Next());
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

        }

        private static void Consume()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumed-" + _bq.Dequeue());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your Semaphore's capacity is 2 but you enqueue 100 items... See a BlockingQueue implementation with an upper limit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841390/how-to-use-a-mutex

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270891(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @David capacity is 2 means 2 threads can run concurrently, isn't it ?

Comment: @L.B capacity is 2 means 2 threads can run concurrently, isn't it ?

Comment: @ShrShr Read the documentation for the constructor and find out for yourself.

Comment: @ShrShr http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235727(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Servy It says the maximum number of requests for the semaphore that can be granted concurrently, means at a time only two threads can run.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the semaphore to control the number of concurrent threads, you're using it wrong. You should acquire the semaphore when you dequeue an item, and release the semaphore when the thread is done processing that item.

What you have right now is a system that allows only two items to be in the queue at any one time. Initially, your semaphore has a count of 2. Each time you enqueue an item, the count is reduced. After two items, the count is 0 and if you try to release again you're going to get a semaphore full exception.

If you really want to do this with a semaphore, you need to remove the `Release` call from the `Enqueue` method. And add a `Release` method to the `BlockingQueue` class. You then would write:

```
    private static void Consume()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumed-" + _bq.Dequeue());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            bq.Release();
        }

    }
```

That would make your code work, but it's not a very good solution. A much better solution would be to use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) and two persistent consumers. Something like:

```
private BlockingCollection<int> bq = new BlockingCollection<int>();

void Test()
{
    // create two consumers
    var c1 = new Thread(Consume);
    var c2 = new Thread(Consume);
    c1.Start();
    c2.Start();
    // produce
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        bq.Add(i);
    }
    bq.CompleteAdding();

    c1.Join();
    c2.Join();
}

void Consume()
{
    foreach (var i in bq.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consumed-" + i);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

That gives you two persistent threads consuming the items. The benefit is that you avoid the cost of spinning up a new thread (or having the RTL assign a pool thread) for each item. Instead, the threads do non-busy waits on the queue. You also don't have to worry about explicit locking, etc. The code is simpler, more robust, and much less likely to contain a bug.